# Wordpress Walker 4 different ID

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, nav

I'm now working on a walker function to add directly to my wordpress menu (nav). The Walker is working great, but, I have a problem (question), here is my code :

```
class WPSE_78121_Sublevel_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<div class='dropdown-sub' id='dropdown-'><div class='dd-e'>
    <ul>\n";
}
function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul></div></div></div>\n";
}
}
```

on the line :

```
$output .= "\n$indent<div class='dropdown-sub' id='dropdown-'><div class='dd-e'>
```

I would like to have 4 different ids (one for each menu generator) only one id per each div, but 4 different one, like dropdown-first, dropdown-second...
How I can do that ? Or is there an other way to do that ?

Thank you 
Bernard

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
     * @param  array $args    Additional strings.
     * @return void
     */
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    // depth dependent classes
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
    $classes = array(
        'nav-submenu',
        ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
        ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
        'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
        );
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

    // build html
    $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
}

    function start_el(  &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

    // depth dependent classes
    $depth_classes = array(
        ( $depth == 0 ? 'nav-item' : 'nav-submenu-item' ),
        ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ),
        ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
        'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
    );
    $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

    // passed classes
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

    // build html
    $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

    // link attributes
    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ' class="menu-link ' . ( $depth > 0 ? 'sub-menu-link' : 'main-menu-link' ) . '"';

    $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
        $args->before,
        $attributes,
        $args->link_before,
        apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
        $args->link_after,
        $args->after
    );

    // build html
    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}
}
```

Comment: I tryed your code, but didn't worked. It is adding depth-1 to each ul, but I really want to keep my code architecture div div ul. But thank you for your help Ris

Comment: you can add your structure this si just a example . you can use depth in your code .

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try do use depth thank you. I'm a wordpress beginner so it's not always easy to understand everything. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: It's quite difficult, I really don't know how I can change your code to add your code in mine. Can you help more, can you tell me how I can just put 4 different IDs in the div ? To generate 4 different IDs of a div for the 4 different menu I have ?

Comment: Hey Ris, I can do that sure, wordpress is generating the first part of my menu (which is ok), and I want to add a second part in this nav, with walker. With this link you will see what I want for the second part (with as you can see, a different ID for each dropdown-sub class div). Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/broy/pb7x6bt4/  Thank you

Comment: can't you create two menus for these?? that will simple and can do this without any walker

Comment: The fact is I need 4 of these menus. But I have already multiple menu because the website will be in 5 differents languages, it's why I need 1 menu per language, and there is 4 submenu for each menu. But if you want I can show you the JS I have done. (It's a dropdown menu). Perhaps you know another way to do it. https://jsfiddle.net/broy/eeg9r3rb/1/

Comment: Did you find a solution Ris ?